# Reverse geocoding from google maps API

Tags: google-maps, jquery

I use the Google Maps API to save a database of addresses in a point.

Came across a problem which is the third day I can not decide. Can you give me some advise.

I cycle runs through all the points, which are marked on the map, in which using geotsoder.geoсode recognize and and use ajax write this address in the database.

Example:

```
function saveAddress(marker_points)
{
    var i = 0;
    id = 0;
    address = [];
    var count  = 0;
    points = [];
    for(i in marker_points) 
    {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( {'address': marker_points[i]},function(results, status){
            address = results[0].formatted_address;
        });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/user.view.location.phone_id-{/literal}{$iPhoneId}{literal}.html",
        cache: false,
        data:  "address=" + address + "&location_point=" + marker_points[i],
        dataType: "html",
        async: false,
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function (data) {
        }
    }); 
}
}
```

But in Ajax passed last point, ie written in the database returned last address and the last point on which this address.

Could you tell me what could be the problem and how to solve it, because he had tried all the options, it does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function closure to associate the request with the response.

[Example using geocoded addresses:](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_geocoder_multiplePoints.html)

They function that gets closure on "i" is:

```
function geocodeAddress(i) {
    geocoder.geocode({'address' : locations[i]},
       function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
             createMarker(results[0].geometry.location, i);
          } else {
             alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: '
                    + status);
          }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your script may sometimes call ajax method before getting response from geocoder.geocode. Try to put $.ajax method inside of

```
function(results, status){
    address = results[0].formatted_address;
}
```

so that fragment of your code would look something like:

```
var marker_points = ["50.463425,30.508120","50.465822,30.514380","50.465317,30.515609"];

for(i in marker_points) {   
       codeAndSendAddress(marker_points[i]);
}

function codeAndSendAddress(point){
    var mp = point.split(',');//Extract numbes from string
    var latLng =  new google.maps.LatLng(mp[0],mp[1]) // create latitude/logitude object


    geocoder.geocode( { 'latLng': latLng}, function(results, status) {
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { make sure location was found

            var geocodedAddress = results[0].formatted_address;
            var geocodedLocationPoint = results[0].geometry.location;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/user.view.location.phone_id-{/literal}{$iPhoneId}{literal}.html",
                data: 'address='+geocodedAddress+
                '&geocoded_location_point='+geocodedLocationPoint+
                '&location_point='+point,
                timeout: 5000,
                success: function (data) {}
            });

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I suggest instead of data:  "address=" + address + "&location_point=" + marker_points[i] You may simply pass an object: data:{address:address, location_point:marker_points[i]} This will help you avoid all problems with escaping special characters in your query string

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it has not worked

Still for all address the latter point is taken

Comment: Ok, 2 things: 1) Can you show some examples what variable marker_points contains? 2) why do you declare address = []; ? I put some changes

Comment: 1) marker_points have json ["50.463425,30.508120","50.465822,30.514380","50.465317,30.515609"]    2) Sorry, my mistake, was left out of the previous attempt. But still, if the variable var address = "" to write, it will be the same problem (will peredavatsya last point - "50.465317,30.515609")

Comment: That information helps me a lot! I was able to reproduce the issue and fix it on my machine please see the changes above.